# Which directory in my Bazaar hierarchy should be the Eclipse project directory?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, project-management, directory

This may be a silly question, but I've decided to switch my Python project from Spyder IDE to Eclipse. And now I'm not sure which directory should I choose as main project directory.

I'm used to selecting `src`, but now I use Bazaar instead of git and I have `trunk` folder and `src`, `doc`, etc. inside of it.

So, should I choose `project`, `project/trunk` or `project/trunk/src` as main directory? If there's no rule on it, which one do you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have never branched your project you should be working out of project/trunk/src. If you're switching to Eclipse look into Bazaar integration. I am using svn. I just checkout the entire project using Eclipse SVN perspective and the resulting project structure resembles the SVN repo. You just have to understand trunks/branches/tags to get it organized correctly.